# python3: disabling print statement depending on server

Tags: django, python-3.x

How can one disable the buildin `print function` depending on the server enviroment? The code below seems to be working
but I'm looking for a cleaner way to do it. I want to use this in a django app.
It would be nice if `print` kept working on localhost.

```
import sys

class MyFileWrapper(object):
    def write(self, *args):
        pass
    def flush(self):
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    print('will be printed')
    sys.stdout = MyFileWrapper()
    print("won't be printed ")
```

Comment: Consider using a logging library, rather than print statements?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I tried the logging module once but I run into problems and it was just too easy to use print. But I think I will give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stop *all* writing to stdout, you can do `sys.stdout = None` (or, if you want to be slightly more pedantic, `sys.stdout = open(os.devnull)`).  As far as changing behavior depending on your environment, you may be able to distinguish between them based on the results of (say) [`socket.gethostname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname).  Alternatively, you can set an environment variable on either the server or your local box (but not both) and then test [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) for the variable's presence or value.

You may be better off using the built-in [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module instead of `print()` calls.  That will allow much more fine-grained control over which things get logged and where the logs go.